# Condition in YAML not working and always skips

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

###### Based on repo, project and branch name trying (which triggers the build) to call a template file, this I am able to get as expected.

###### Below is the snippet, which I am trying to call another template from main pipeline and is not working. Condition is not working while comparing the variable. Is am missing anything?

```
  - script: |
      repoName=$(Build.Repository.Name)
      branchName=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
      repouri=$(echo "$(Build.Repository.Uri)")
      prjname=$(echo "$repouri" | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-2)}')
      pattern="$prjname:$(Build.Repository.ID):$(Build.Repository.Name)"
      echo "Repository Name: $repoName"
      echo "Branch Name: $branchName"
      echo "Project Name: $prjname"
      if [[ $repoName == "DevOps_Practice" && $prjname == "DevOps_Practice" ]]; then
        echo "Triggering pipeline for $repoName for project $prjname"
        template="DevOps_Practice"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=templateName]$template"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=repoName]$repoName"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branch_name]$branchName"
      else
        echo "No matching pipeline found."
      fi
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo "With $(templateName)" ## **I can see the proper value as expected**
  - ${{ if eq(variables['$(templateName)'], 'DevOps_Practice' ) }}: ## **Not Working**
  - ${{ if eq(variables['templateName'], 'DevOps_Practice' ) }}: ## **Not Working**
    - template: DevOps_Practice.yaml
      parameters:
        repo_name: $repoName
        branch_name: $branchName
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#how-can-i-use-variables-inside-of-templates): *Parameters are expanded early in processing a pipeline run so not all variables are available.*.
It means that you can't use the variables set in the previous step in the ${{ if .. }} condition.

To see what predefined variables are available in templates, see [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops).

Taking into consideration the abovementioned you can use the following approach to insert the template conditionally and inject parameters into it:

```
steps:
- ${{ if and(eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'DevOps_Practice'),eq(variables['System.TeamProject'], 'DevOps_Practice')) }}: 
  - template: DevOps_Practice.yaml
    parameters:
      repo_name: $(Build.Repository.Name)
      branch_name: $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```